# What are the downsides of a large realpath_cache_ttl setting?

Tags: php, php-fpm

I've been researching and tweaking both `realpath_cache_size` and `realpath_cache_ttl`, but I'm not clear on what the consequences are if I set `realpath_cache_ttl` too high.

[The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) states the following:

> Duration of time (in seconds) for which to cache realpath information for a given file or directory. For systems with rarely changing files, consider increasing the value.

Okay, great.  How much can I increase it?  What happens if I increase it too much?  *Can* I increase it too much?

Also, if it matters, I'm using PHP 7 FPM, but I would like to understand how large values of `realpath_cache_ttl` would affect non-FPM installs as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's like any time-based cache expiry: if you set it too high, then you'll have all sorts of mysterious and hard-to-track-down problems when the reality (the realpath target) changes, with processes that have the out-of-date information cached using the wrong results, probably resulting in trying to read files that no longer exist, but possibly writing to directories that no longer exist, or all manner of other problems.

Comment: I'm looking for specifics.  What do you mean when you say, "too high"?  The default for this value is two minutes.  That seems high enough that it would already cause the kinds of things you're talking about, and yet it doesn't, which is why I want specific details.

Comment: You're not going to get a specific answer to a non-specific question.

Comment: To me the question seemed specific enough - and I would also like to hear the answer: what is too high? If I update the code on the server, will php be not aware of the changes in the next random period of 0 to 120s?
If 600s is too high because of possible mysterious issues, then why they don't  ever happen in 2 minutes time?